# WSCRIPT error: subscript out of range

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript which tries to merge data from two CSV files based upon common field. When I am running my script, then I get an error on Line 5 char 1:

> Subscript out of range.

The two files which I am trying to merge based upon the value of a  common field between the two are in the same folder where script is also placed.

My code is :

```
    'Instatiate FSO.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Open the CSV file for reading. The file is in the same folder as the script and named csv_sample.csv.

Wscript.Echo "Path " & objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
'Open the store locations file first
Set brandCSV = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\" & "SizeGuideLookup_test.csv",1,False)
'Set header status to account for the first line as the column headers.
IsHeader = True
'Initialize the var for the output string.
OutRecord = ""
'Read each line of the file.
Wscript.Echo "Starting Brand File loop"
Do Until brandCSV.AtEndOfStream
    brandLine = brandCSV.ReadLine
    If IsHeader Then
        OutTxt = "PIM Size Type,PIM Identifier,Structure Group,PIM Size Groupd Value Lookup,Size Group To Upload" & vbCrLf
        IsHeader = False
    Else
        'parse brandrecord and get brand id
        brandLineArray=Split(brandLine,";")
        brandBrandId = brandLineArray(0)
        ' loop through Store Location file and get matching data
        foundLocation=false
        Set storeLocCSV = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\" & "SizeGuideMapping.csv",1,False)
        Do Until storeLocCSV.AtEndOfStream
            outLine=""
            storeLine=storeLocCSV.ReadLine
            storeLineArray=Split(storeLine,";")
            storeBrandId = storeLineArray(0)
            'if the brand IDs match, append the brand data to the end of the store data.
            If brandBrandId = storeBrandId Then
              ' match found - ouptut data (specific fields from store Line + brand line)
              outLine = outLine & brandLineArray(0)
              outLine = outLine & "," & brandLineArray(1)
              outLine = outLine & "," & brandLineArray(2)
                          outLine = outLine & "," & storeLineArray(1)
              outLine = outLine & "," & storeLineArray(1)
              foundLocation=true
              'append created line to end of output text data
              OutTxt = OutTxt & outLine & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
        'Close the store location file.
        storeLocCSV.close   
        'if we havent found the data, add empty fields to end of line
        if foundLocation=false Then
            ' no locations for this brand - create brand-only record
            outLine = brandLineArray(0) & ",,," 
                        outLine = outLine & "," & brandLineArray(1)
            outLine = outLine & "," & brandLineArray(2)
                        outLine = outLine & "," & storeLineArray(1)
            outLine = outLine & "," & storeLineArray(1)
            'append created line to end of output text data
            OutTxt = OutTxt & outLine & vbCrLf
        end if
    End If
Loop
'Close the brand file.
brandCSV.Close
'Open the output file for writing.
Set objOutCSV = objFSO.CreateTextFile(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\" & "brandfile.csv",True)
'Write the var OutTxt to the file overwriting existing contents.
objOutCSV.Write OutTxt
'Close the file.
objOutCSV.Close
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you drag the folder to the script? Or how do you start it? Or short: What does your Wscript.Arguments(0) contain?

Comment: Judging by `Wscript.Echo "Path " & WScript.Arguments(0)` I'd say a file path. It's likely the `WScript.Arguments(0)` causing the error so as @JulianKuchlbauer says we need to know how you call the script and what is passed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i am right, you want to get the folder path of the executing script.

For this purpose, you don't want to use `WScript.Arguments(0)` but `FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)`.

Comment: I don't drag the folder to the script. To run script, I just right click on it and run using Microsoft Windows based script host. I updated my script above based upon your suggestion and now I am not getting any errors but I am not getting desired output either. I want to see the value of StorelineArray from second column in the 4th and 5th column of output file (which is SizeGuideLookup_test.csv)

Comment: My script is working now. It is still not exactly what I want but at least I can see the matching result based upon common field between two elements. If I need further help then I will raise another question.

Answer (score 0):

The line the error occurs on doesn't tally with the source you have provided *(guessing that's not all of it)* but it's likely the

```
WScript.Arguments(0)
```

causing the `Subscript out of range` error as the script is expecting an argument *(`WshUnnamed` or `WshNamed` objects)* being passed but there doesn't appear to be one at index `0` in the `WshArguments` collection object.

If the argument is indeed a file path, then you want to be calling it with either `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` something like this *(at a Command Prompt)*;

```
cscript.exe /nologo "yourscript.vbs" "C:\some\file\path"
```

Then when

```
WScript.Echo "Path " & WScript.Arguments(0)
```

is called you should get *(based off this example)*

```
C:\some\file\path
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Arguments Property (WScript Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [WshArguments Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss1ysb2a(v=vs.84).aspx)